# Will my device's location be shown in Find My iPhone if it is connected to iTunes?

Tags: iphone, icloud, find-my-iphone, activation-lock

Two days ago I lost my iPhone 5s. It could have been stolen.
I've reported it to my carrier and police yesterday as stolen.

I got Find My iPhone enabled, but when I login to iCloud there is no information (the device is shown as offline). I hope someone will start my phone, therefore…

If the person who stole/found my iPhone will try to connect it to iTunes and try to restore the iPhone, will Find My iPhone show me the location of the phone? I'm a little scared because I found a way to disable activation called iCloud Bypass.

If it possible I will not find my phone, but if my iPhone sends me its location during the bypass process or even if someone will try to restore the device in iTunes, I will find a thief. Does anybody know anything about that Find My iPhone functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to Lost Mode on https://www.icloud.com/#find

If anyone ever tries to reset the phone it will have to go online to activate.
At that point, Lost Mode will kick in [possibly with a location]

The phone is a brick to anyone else, without your login details.

Don't erase it remotely, send a message to it, perhaps informing the current "holder" that it's locked & how to contact you or the police to report they "found" it.

Thieves are finally getting the message that stealing an iPhone is pointless. Thefts are down 40% from last year.

Comment: Great thanks to you: Testsujin. Its good the phone is brick to anyone else without my icloud login and password, and im satisfied for now about possibility of future localization, i will activate Lost Mode as soon as possible, and send a message with my phone number to contact in case of found. And i will wait for email with informations from icloud. Yes, find my iphone decrease level of stolen iphones.
But i was so scared and shocked when i read "It can be bypassed"
I hope i will get my phone back. Thanks for help once again... :)